# Remove the gray color border in android spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hi i have to develop one spinner app.
here how can i remove the default gray color border on android spinner item..please help me.

[image]

How can i remove the default border from this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't a simple form to do that you want with code or other simple method

You must to create your own background for that spinner o use other theme  -- light, dark, holo ... -- I think Holo its a good solution.

If your app is developing for Android 3- you can use this https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere to use Holo in every Android version 1-6+

Other solution is take the Android resources for that compoment and edit it with Gimp/photoshop and use the editing image.

I hope this help you